# How to Edit .pps files?

Tags: ms-office

They open like power-points in Powerpoint with animations. I would like to maintain the animations. There are just a few mistakes that I would like to correct in the body.

---

How can you edit .pps files and maintain the animations of the presentation?

Answer (score 2):

In PowerPoint, choose File → Open… and manually navigate to the file in the Open dialog. This opens the presentation normally and you can edit it just like any other PowerPoint presentation.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! My mistake in tagging. Corrected now.